# terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException caused by firebase

Tags: ios, swift, flutter

I facing a problem when running the app on IOS only the app crash from beginning .The App is working on the Android , but not on IOS
I face some problem when running the app with two plugins smart look and flutter freshchat , but I can handle with these error by deleting pod file and make flutter freshchat folder as public

I looking for many solution but nothing solve the problem

I Used Xcode 11.6

Error

```
2020-08-04 09:28:31.629532+0300 Runner[55327:357948] 6.29.0 - [Firebase/Core][I-COR000012] Could not locate configuration file: 'GoogleService-Info.plist'.
2020-08-04 09:28:31.673649+0300 Runner[55327:357998] flutter: Observatory listening on http://127.0.0.1:61149/gGQPi_bDYqA=/
2020-08-04 09:28:31.825074+0300 Runner[55327:357355] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.firebase.core', reason: '`[FIRApp configure];` (`FirebaseApp.configure()` in Swift) could not find a valid GoogleService-Info.plist in your project. Please download one from https://console.firebase.google.com/.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23e3de6e __exceptionPreprocess + 350
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff512539b2 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23e3dcac +[NSException raise:format:] + 188
    3   Runner                              0x00000001021a5e92 +[FIRApp configure] + 130
    4   Runner                              0x000000010201439b $s6Runner11AppDelegateC11application_29didFinishLaunchingWithOptionsSbSo13UIApplicationC_SDySo0j6LaunchI3KeyaypGSgtF + 251
    5   Runner                              0x0000000102014723 $s6Runner11AppDelegateC11application_29didFinishLaunchingWithOptionsSbSo13UIApplicationC_SDySo0j6LaunchI3KeyaypGSgtFTo + 211
    6   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4931c614 -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 232
    7   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff4931dfb3 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesWithActions:forCanvas:payload:fromOriginatingProcess:] + 3985
    8   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff49323b75 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1226
    9   UIKitCore                           0x00007fff48a2c16d -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer completeApplicationLaunchWithFBSScene:transitionContext:] + 122
    10  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff48f37ba1 _UIScenePerformActionsWithLifecycleActionMask + 83
    11  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff48a2cc7f __101-[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:]_block_invoke + 198
    12  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff48a2c68e -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _performBlock:withApplicationOfDeactivationReasons:fromReasons:] + 296
    13  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff48a2caac -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:] + 818
    14  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff48a2c341 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer uiScene:transitionedFromState:withTransitionContext:] + 345
    15  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff48a30932 __186-[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:]_block_invoke_2 + 178
    16  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff48e4dc8d +[BSAnimationSettings(UIKit) tryAnimatingWithSettings:actions:completion:] + 852
    17  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff48f562fe _UISceneSettingsDiffActionPerformChangesWithTransitionContext + 240
    18  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff48a3064d __186-[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:]_block_invoke + 153
    19  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff48f56201 _UISceneSettingsDiffActionPerformActionsWithDelayForTransitionContext + 84
    20  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff48a304bb -[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:] + 381
    21  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff48884eb8 __64-[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 657
    22  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff48883a77 -[UIScene _emitSceneSettingsUpdateResponseForCompletion:afterSceneUpdateWork:] + 253
    23  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff48884be2 -[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 210
    24  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff493220bd -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 512
    25  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff48e747bc -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 361
    26  FrontBoardServices                  0x00007fff36d37d2e -[FBSSceneImpl _callOutQueue_agent_didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 419
    27  FrontBoardServices                  0x00007fff36d5ddc1 __86-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient sceneID:createWithParameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.154 + 102
    28  FrontBoardServices                  0x00007fff36d42757 -[FBSWorkspace _calloutQueue_executeCalloutFromSource:withBlock:] + 220
    29  FrontBoardServices                  0x00007fff36d5da52 __86-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient sceneID:createWithParameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 355
    30  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010744ae8e _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    31  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010744dda2 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 300
    32  FrontBoardServices                  0x00007fff36d836e9 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 30
    33  FrontBoardServices                  0x00007fff36d833d7 -[FBSSerialQueue _queue_performNextIfPossible] + 441
    34  FrontBoardServices                  0x00007fff36d838e6 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 22
    35  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23da1c91 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    36  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23da1bbc __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 76
    37  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23da1394 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 180
    38  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23d9bf8e __CFRunLoopRun + 974
    39  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff23d9b8a4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 404
    40  GraphicsServices                    0x00007fff38c39bbe GSEventRunModal + 139
    41  UIKitCore                           0x00007fff49325968 UIApplicationMain + 1605
    42  Runner                              0x00000001020148cb main + 75
    43  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff520ce1fd start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

the depancies that I used on the app :

```
scoped_model: ^1.0.1
  http: ^0.12.2
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.6+3
  intl: ^0.16.0
  sliding_up_panel: ^0.3.4 
  carousel_slider: ^2.1.0
  flutter_calendar_carousel: any
  keyboard_avoider: ^0.1.2
  mobile_popup: ^1.2.0
  easy_listview: ^0.1.3
  sqflite: ^1.2.2+1
  crclib: ^1.0.1
  firebase_core: ^0.4.5
  firebase_auth: ^0.16.1
  cloud_firestore: ^0.13.7
  flutter_html: ^0.11.1
  flutter_material_color_picker: ^1.0.3
  auto_size_text: ^2.1.0
  # loadmore: ^1.0.4
  sticky_headers: "^0.1.8"
  webview_flutter: ^0.3.19+9
  connectivity: ^0.4.9
  expandable: ^4.1.3
  path_provider: ^1.6.11
  url_launcher: ^5.2.7
  # flutter_typeahead: ^1.8.0
  find_dropdown: ^0.2.0
  geolocator: ^5.1.4+2
  google_maps_flutter: ^0.5.21+8
  location: ^2.3.5
  permission_handler: ^5.0.1+1
  loading_indicator: ^1.1.0
  # localstorage: ^2.0.0
  photo_view: ^0.9.0
  maps_launcher: ^1.0.1 
  flutter_offline: "^0.3.0"
  # fluttertoast: ^7.0.1+1
  google_maps_webservice: ^0.0.16
  flutter_google_places: ^0.2.3
  flutter_datetime_picker: ^1.3.1
  flutter_date_pickers: ^0.0.6
  circular_bottom_navigation: ^1.0.1
  progress_dialog: ^1.2.0
  flutter_fluid_slider: ^1.0.2
  lazy_load_scrollview: ^1.1.0
  holding_gesture: ^0.0.3
  firebase_remote_config: ^0.3.1+1
  cached_network_image: ^2.0.0
  rxdart: ^0.23.0
  package_info: ^0.4.0+13
  firebase_analytics: ^5.0.16
  dio: ^3.0.9
  duration: ^2.0.11 
  flutter_freshchat: ^1.3.2
  firebase_messaging: ^6.0.16
  firebase_dynamic_links: ^0.5.3
  share: ^0.6.4+1
  firebase_crashlytics: ^0.1.4+1
  smartlook: ^1.0.1
  search_map_place: ^0.1.1
  dio_http_cache: ^0.2.6
  flutter_staggered_animations: ^0.1.2
  shimmer: ^1.1.1
  flutter_progress_button: ^1.0.0
  flutter_inappwebview: ^4.0.0+4
  device_info: ^0.4.2+4
```

And the AppDelgate.swift that showed the error

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import GoogleMaps
import Firebase


@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    
    GMSServices.provideAPIKey("AIzaSyBdi_rTaOCYcqtx1xCdChTg5-pol9EQHfo")
        FirebaseApp.configure()
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
  
}
```

Flutter Doctor Result

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.5, on Mac OS X 10.15.4 19E287, locale en-BH)
 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.6)
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.47.3)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)

• No issues found!
```

Comment: Did you read the reason and follow the suggestion: *could not find a valid GoogleService-Info.plist in your project. Please download one from https://console.firebase.google.com/.*

Answer (score 0):

The error quite clear though:

```
reason: '`[FIRApp configure];` (`FirebaseApp.configure()` in Swift) 
could not find a valid GoogleService-Info.plist in your project. 
Please download one from https://console.firebase.google.com/.'
```

You don't have the Google .plist file in your project.

---> You need to get the `GoogleService-Info.plist` file and add it to your project.

Comment: Already I have GoogleService-Info.plist file in the app file

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a GoogleService-Info.plist, you said you do have it but if it is named anything other than 'GoogleService-Info.plist' the app will crash, like what you get. e.g Your 'GoogleService-Info.plist' might be named 'GoogleService-Info(1).plist' because you might have 2 files with that name or maybe you accidentally deleted your GoogleService-Info.plist in the finder. If you moved your 'GoogleService-Info.plist' to a different folder(like from the download folder to the desktop), that would cause an issue too.

If none of these work then there might be a bug with the app or some other thing related to these.